# interpretation of bins in matplotlib hist

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, scipy

What is the interpretation of the `bins` argument to `matplotlib.hist` if it is a sequence? Is it the same as numpy's `bins` argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is the same. It defines the number of intervals for your data. Giving a sequence allows you to have unequally large bins, both in numpy and matplotlib. You'll find detailed help on this in [numpy's](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) and [matplotlib's](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist) documentation of the `hist` command.